# If I can't use f11 to add a .bib file in texWorks, what can I do instead?

Tags: bibtex

I watched a tutorial on using bibtex, [How to Generate References with LaTeX (BibTeX)](https://youtu.be/KS9GvK7cvmo), and the trick for getting it to work is using `f11 - f1` keys.

Meaning,

1. Create a .bib file and a .tex file,
2. In the .tex file use the bibliography style environment, like this: `\bibliographystyle{apacite}` and
   `\bibliography{biblio.bib}`
3. Type `f11` many times followed by `f1`.

I would like to know the non keyboard shortcut of `f11`, and `f1`, please. Because al the f keys on my keyboard are not easy to deduce in an HP laptop running Windows 10 and TexWorks.  I have a .bib file, but the keyboard shortcuts do not work for me, and when I try to compile the file, it says

```
The style file: apacite.bst
I found no \citation commands---while reading file CSMC_MUME_LaTeX_Template.aux
Database file #1: biblio.bib
apacite.bst [2013/07/21 v6.03 APA bibliography style]
(There was 1 error message)

Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed.
```

biblio.bib file is in the same folder as the .tex file.

Comment: You are running BibTeX, so your F11 key is working correctly. If you look closely you can see that BibTeX complains `I found no \citation commands---while reading file CSMC_MUME_LaTeX_Template.aux`. That means that you did not use `\cite` (or a related command) in your document. BibTeX will only produces a bibliography of the entries you cited, unless you explicitly use `\nocite{<key>}` to add a specific entry to the bibliography without citing it in the text or `\nocite{*}` to add all entries to the bibliography list without citing them. ...

Comment: ... Pick one entry from your `.bib` file and `\cite` it in your document. E.g. write `\cite{sigfridsson}` somewhere in the text if you have an entry `sigfridsson` in the text. Then compile with LaTeX, then with BibTeX and again with LaTeX.

Comment: @moewe And do you have any idea why it happened that when I added NEW bibliography in the .bib document then compiled with bibtex then latex, the referred cite still appeared with question mark? Like this: `(?.?).`

Comment: Not quite sure, but you may want to try just running LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX again. When you add a new citation in the `.tex` file you first need to run LaTeX and only then BibTeX and LaTeX (twice) again to make sure it gets picked up correctly.